# Mac OS X, Ubuntu dual installed incorrectly; what is the preferred way to go back and try again?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mac, reboot

I thought I had installed rEFInd Boot Manager correctly, partitioned my Mac HD to reserve 30GB for Ubuntu, and when I rebooted my computer, I could chose between operating systems.

Unfortunately, this does not work. Ubuntu is now the only operating system available, and I have no permission rights to my Macbook files.

Thankfully, I have everything backed up on a Seagate external hard drive.

What is the preferred method to start over and try again?

Comment: Did you get your dual boot working?

Comment: @DavidAnderson No, I gave up. Apple wins. They've made it so bloody difficult nowadays.

Comment: I asked the question because I just installed a triple boot of OS X 10.10.3, Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04.2 on a mid 2007 iMac. And yes, it was bloody difficult. If others can get it working using my procedure, I will let you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably only need to hold alt/option and select macintosh HD to boot from. From within OS X reinstall refind using the ./install.sh

Otherwise to do this from scratch, use the following instructions:

Reformat the drive completely using gparted.
Install osx yosemite:

1. in the install phase, use Disk Utility to format your desired space for Macintosh HD using journaled case sensitive. Save the remainder of your HD as "freespace"
   2.after install of OS X is complete, bootup and enable the filevault.
2. after filevault is complete, install refind using the ./install.sh
3. install ubuntu with the bootable usb from refind
4. on boot, hold alt/option and select macintosh HD.
5. reinstall refind ./install.sh

should be good to go. Whenever you install a new linux system you will need to reinstall refind.